# Mapping JSON data in JQGrid

Tags: json, jqgrid, jqgrid-php, subgrid

I am using jqGrid  3.6.4 and a jquery 1.4.2 . in my sample i am getting following json data format & i want to map these json data into rows of a jqgrid

```
{
"page": "1",
"total": 1,
"records": "6",
"rows": [
    {
        "head": {
            "student_name": "Mr S. Jack ",
            "year": 2007

        },
        "sub": [
            {
                "course_description": "Math ",
                "date": "22-04-2010",
                "number": 1,
                "time_of_add": "2:00",
                "day": "today"
            }
        ]

      }
]
}
```

my jqgrid code is as follows

```
jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
url:"http://localhost/stud/beta/web/GetStud.php?sid="+sid,
dtatype: "json",
colNames: ['Stud Name','Year','Date'.'Number'],
colModel: [ {name:'Stud Name',index:'student_name', width:100, jsonmap:"student_name"},
{name:'Year',index:'year', width:100, jsonmap:"year"},
{name:'Date',index:'date', width:100, jsonmap:"date"},
{name:'Number',index:'number', width:100, jsonmap:"number"}
],
height:'100%',
jsonReader: { repeatitems : false, root:"head" },
});
```

So now the problem is as my data i.e. student_name and year is under "head" , the jqgrid is enable to locate these two fields. at the same time other two column values i.e. Date and Number lies under "sub" and even those columns i am not be able to map it with jqgrid

so kindly help me how to located these attributes in JQGrid.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain why "sub" element is an array? Do you want to use subgrids or you can change Input data from sub:[{"":"", ...}] to sub:{"":"", ...}? One more question: what do you want to use as a row id? student_name? Or you forget to include is in the JSON data?

Comment: Can you change the JSON data which server send back or you call a service, which you not control?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all the code posted has some errors like `dtatype: "json"` instead of `datatype: "json"`. "`},});`" instead of "`}});`" at the end of code and `colNames: ['Stud Name','Year','Date'.'Number']` instead of `colNames: ['Stud Name','Year','Date','Number']`. After fixing this clear bugs you need change `jsonmap` values. This was your main question. The fixed code will be look like following:

```js
jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
    ...
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['Stud Name','Year','Date'.'Number'],
    colModel: [
        {name:'student_name', width:100, jsonmap:"head.student_name"},
        {name:'year', width:100, jsonmap:"head.year"},
        {name:'date', width:100, jsonmap:"sub.0.date"},
        {name:'number', width:100, jsonmap:"sub.0.number"}
    ],
    jsonReader: { repeatitems:false, root:"rows" }
});
```

You have to fix `root` to "`rows`" and use `jsonmap` in **JSON dot notation** (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_dot_notation). I use a little strange notation like "`sub.0.number`" because `sub.0.number` in JavaScript is the same as `sub[0].number`. It works now.

I recommend you think one more about the structure of JSON data which you receive. (see my previous comments to you question): Is "sub" element is really an array with always one element or you want to use subgrids? Probably the data should be changed from `sub:[{"":"", ...}]` to `sub:{"":"", ...}`? What do you want to use as a rowid? `student_name`? Then add `id: "head.student_name"` to the `jsonReader` definition or add `key: true` property to the definition of the column `student_name`. Or you forget to include it in the JSON data?

And the last suggestion. If you open http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and opens on the left side of tree the branch "Data Mapping" \ "Data optimization" you will see an example where on use only array instead of named elements in JSON. Such data will be have minimum size and can be transferred more quickly from server to client. You data instead have some fields (like "**course_description**") which you don't use at all. So **if you can make any changes in the server** code try to optimize the data transfer rate.